# Paper under review in a reputed Math journal for 7 months

Tags: mathematics, peer-review

I have submitted a paper in a reputed math journal. It is under review for 7 months. 2 month ago I inquired and I was told that one reviewer has sent review and they are waiting for the other review.

Is it time common in Math journal

Comment: Yes, it's common, or at least not uncommon. It also depends on the length of your paper. For a 50 page manuscript, your story sounds fairly common and reasonable. For a 10 page paper, not so much.

Comment: @DanRomik: it is 20 page.